# Azure CosmosDB SQL API createDatabaseAsync does not create database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Azure CosmosDB SQL API. I have an Asynchronous task to Connect to my AzureCosmosDB Account and I am trying to create a database through code.

Following is my code Snippet

```
private async Task ConnectToDocumentDB()
{
this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
Console.WriteLine(client.WriteEndpoint);
Database db = await this.client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "MyDB" });
Console.WriteLine("Response --" + db.Id);           
}
```

When I view the Client's EndPonit in console to ensure the AzureCosmosDb Connection, I am able to view the correct EndPoint. But when I try to create the Database, it doesn't create database.

The method call to this asynchronous task from main method is as follows

```
 Program p = new Program();
 p.ConnectToDocumentDB().Wait();
```

I dont know where I am going wrong.Help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try debugging through the code? What is the response from CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync? The response is a `ResourceResponse<Database>` with an implicit operator so I'd rather you returned that instead so we can debug it using the response metadata.

Comment: @NickChapsas Yes!I tried debugging the code. But when the program control reaches the createDatabaseAsync Method call the program terminates and no exception is also thrown.So I am not able to view the ResourceResponse.

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in a try-catch and see if it is an exception that your exception settings are ignoring? Also don't use `.Wait()` on Program. Use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead.

Comment: @NickChapsas Thanks! It works fine now

Comment: I wrote up the answer. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your applicaiton's context, `.Wait()` can cause a deadlock when your code reaches an `async` call.

You should be using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` so the state machine is properly generated behind the scenes to prevent this issue.